# MySQL and date() query

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have records in a MySQL table that have a unix timestamp in it. How would I go searching, in a MySQL query, for a query that was posted on the current month?

Here's what I have so far:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `postings` WHERE `date_posted` = '".date("m-Y")."'";
```

Obviously -- not right. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your column contains a time() field you'll need values containing time values in order to compare. By using the function `strtotime` you'll achieve what you want.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `postings` 
          WHERE `date_posted` >= ". strtotime("This month") ." 
          AND `date_posted` < ". strtotime("+1 month");
```

Comment: Oh, wow. I was going for something along the lines of this offline. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM postings WHERE date_posted BETWEEN '2011-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-12-31 23:59:59'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: If indeed it is a UNIX timestamp (not a MySQL Datetime/Timestamp), then you'll need to cast the timestamp into a Datetime, like this:

    SELECT * FROM postings WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(date_posted) BETWEEN '2011-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-12-31 23:59:59'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM postings WHERE MONTH(date_posted) = '".date("m")."'";
```

or

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM postings WHERE MONTH(date_posted) = MONTH(NOW())";
```

I didn't try it though.
And also the format you used to save the date matters.